# Symfony 4 SwiftMailer not sending emails

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, symfony4

I'm trying to send an email from a Symfony 4 controller, followed the instructions on on the Symfony 4 docs (https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html).

My .env has the following:

```
//.env
MAILER_URL=smtp://mail.********.com:465?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=support@********.com&password=*********

//swiftmailer.yml
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

To confirm that those settings work, I ran the following in CLI:

```
php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send

SwiftMailer's Interactive Email Sender
======================================

 From:
 > support@******.com

 To:
 > *****@******.com

 Subject:
 > Testing Swift

 Body:
 > This is using the cmdline swiftmailer


 [OK] 1 emails were successfully sent.
```

I checked my email and it worked. Email arrived as expected and I assumed there was nothing else to configure.

From the controller I do this:

```
public function emailTest(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
         $message = (new \Swift_Message())

            // Give the message a subject
            ->setSubject('My test email')

            // Set the From address with an associative array
            ->setFrom(['support@*********.com' => 'someName'])

            // Set the To addresses with an associative array (setTo/setCc/setBcc)
            ->setTo(['**********@gmail.com'])

            // Give it a body
            ->setBody('Test email from Symfony 4.1 Controller')
            ;

        echo $mailer->send($message);
}
```

This the "$mailer->send($message)" returns 1 (True). However, no email was ever sent. I checked the server logs, nothing, I checked the php error longs, nothing. I'm not sure what else to try???

Comment: what environment are you in?

Comment: Mails will also be captured by the Symfony debug toolbar, does it show up? And what exactly is $mailer?

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: I've found solution for myself. After I sent the email, a dumped the variables and give a `die()` command. But, if your spool is memory then: __When you use spooling to store the emails to memory, they will get sent right before the kernel terminates. This means the email only gets sent if the whole request got executed without any unhandled exception or any errors.__